# How to find libraries in Ubuntu Software?

Tags: package-management, software-center

I cannot find any library to install in Ubuntu Software. Prior Ubuntu 16.04 when I typed `libgtk` I got some results. New Ubuntu Software returns with no results.

Is it possible to look for libraries in Ubuntu Software or it looks only for applications?

I'm aware of Synaptic Package Manager.

Answer (score 1):

There are another 2 good choices to add to the Software Center and the Synaptic Package Manger:

**1. Using 'apt-cache search'**

You can open a Terminal and search for all the *-dev* files attached to libgtk as follows:

```
andrew@athens:~$ apt-cache search libgtk | grep dev
libgtksourceview-3.0-dev - development files for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
libgtkspell-dev - Development files for GtkSpell
libgtkspell3-3-dev - Development files for GtkSpell
libgtk-3-dev - development files for the GTK+ library
libgtk2.0-cil-dev - CLI binding for the GTK+ toolkit 2.12
libgtk2.0-dev - development files for the GTK+ library
libgtkmm-2.4-dev - C++ wrappers for GTK+ (development files)
libgtkmm-3.0-dev - C++ wrappers for GTK+ (development files)
libgtk-sharp-beans2.0-cil-dev - Supplementary CLI bindings for GTK 2.14+ - development package
libgtk-vnc-1.0-dev - VNC viewer widget for GTK+2 (development files)
libgtk-vnc-2.0-dev - VNC viewer widget for GTK+3 (development files)
libgtkada-bin - Ada binding for the GTK+ GUI (development utilities)
libgtkada2.24.4-dev - Ada binding for the GTK+ GUI (development files)
libgtkdatabox-0.9.2-0-dev - Gtk+ library to display large amounts of numerical data (development)
libgtkdataboxmm-dev - C++ bindings for GtkDatabox - development files
libgtkglada2.24.4-dev - Ada binding for GTK+ OpenGL extensions (development files)
libgtkglext1-dev - OpenGL Extension to GTK+ (development files)
libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2-dev - C++ bindings for GtkGLExt (Development files)
libgtkhex-3-dev - GNOME Hex editor for files (development headers)
libgtkhotkey-dev - Gtk hotkey static libraries and headers
libgtkimageview-dev - image viewer widget for GTK+ (development files)
libgtkmathview-dev - rendering engine for MathML documents
libgtkpod-dev - main library for the gtkpod package, development kit
libgtksourceview2.0-dev - development files for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
libgtksourceviewmm-3.0-dev - C++ binding of GtkSourceView - development files
liblablgtkmathview-ocaml-dev - OCaml bindings for libgtkmathview, a GTK widget to render MathML
liblablgtksourceview2-ocaml-dev - OCaml bindings for libgtksourceview2, a source editor GTK+ widget
libgtk-dotnet3.0-cil-dev - GTK.NET library - development files
libgtk3.0-cil-dev - CLI binding for the GTK+ toolkit 3.0
libgtkextra-dev - development files for libgtkextra-x11-3.0
libgtkgl2.0-dev - OpenGL context support for GTK+ (development files)
libgtkspellmm-3.0-dev - C++ wrapper library for GtkSpell (development files)
andrew@athens:~$
```

Variations on this type of search are only limited by your knowledge of regular expressions :).

**2. Use the Web...**

I quite often use the very nice web based search here:

Ubuntu Packages Search 
http://packages.ubuntu.com/

There are many, many possibilities in usage to search by Ubuntu Release, package name, file names etc etc. A simple search for libgtk under Xenial [can be seen here...](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgtk&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all)

Several other possibilities but this should hopefully get you started....

Comment: Speaking of alternatives, there's also (old) Ubuntu Software Center. Its option to "Show x technical items" is brilliant.